# Why does Typescript compiler think element in string array would be type 'never'?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that compiled fine in Typescript 3.5.3, but after updating to 3.8.3, throws an incomprehensible error during compilation.

```
  import { isNumber, toInteger, padNumber } from './math';

    parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
      if (value) {
        const dateParts = value.trim().split('/');
        if (dateParts.length === 3
          && isNumber(dateParts[0])
          && isNumber(dateParts[1])
          && isNumber(dateParts[2])
          // force user to enter 4 digit year
          && dateParts[2].length === 4) {      // <-- fails here
          return {month: toInteger(dateParts[0]), day: toInteger(dateParts[1]), year: toInteger(dateParts[2])};
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
```

The `dateParts` variable is a string array - so why, when checking the length of the third element as `dateParts[2].length` is the compiler thinking that the dereferenced value would be of type `never`???

Compilation yields the error below:

```
ERROR in src/app/shared/utils/datepicker-parser-formatter.ts:17:25 - error TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'.

17         && dateParts[2].length === 4) {
                           ~~~~~~
```

`isNumber` is defined as:

```
export function isNumber(value: any): value is number {
  return !isNaN(toInteger(value));
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally also linking to a runnable version in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) (but include all the necessary code here, too).

Comment: How is `isNumber` defined? I'm able to reproduce this issue by defining `isNumber(x: any): x is number`, and the error is because `number & string` is `never`. A value can't be both a number and a string.

Comment: @jtbandes - Smart! Nate, if that's how your `isNumber` is defined, that's what you need to fix. It shouldn't assert that a string is a number. (But that's if jtbandes' guess is right.)

Comment: @jtbandes - You were right. I've posted a CW answer, but I can remove it if you want to post a non-CW one. Please @ ping me if you do. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isNumber` is defined incorrectly. It's asserting that anything that can be *converted* to a number *is* a number. Those are two different things. The correct definition would be something like:

```typescript
export function isNumber(value: any): value is number {
  return typeof value === "number" && !isNaN(value);
}
```

...if you want something that filters out `NaN`. (I didn't filter out fractionsl values.)

As @jtbandes said, since `isNumber` is telling TypeScript that `dateParts[2]` is a `number`, but TypeScript knows from `split` that it's a string, it's trying to apply `string & number` — which is `never`.

You'll want an `isNumeric` or similar along these lines for places like this where you know it's not a number:

```typescript
export function isNumeric(value: any): boolean {
  return !isNaN(toInteger(value));
}
```

Note that it doesn't make the assertion.

Comment: Gotcha.  So we're being too strict with our type assertions and the compiler is more aggressive now.  I removed the "is number" constraint and can now compile.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @NateKennedy - My pleasure! The real thanks goes to jtbandes. They had the great insight.